# How to fix wix "illegal reference to another property"

Tags: wix

I'm trying to fix an issue for a client. They have the below build error:

> The 'WixShellExecTarget' Property contains '[INSTALLFOLDER]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes.

Here's what I think is the relevant snippet:

```xml
    <!-- Open destination folder after install -->
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="EULA" Guid="{32e8fdf3-8a40-471c-8ff6-1ac27e0fae7c}">
        <File Id="eulaRTF" Name="EULA.rtf" DiskId="1" Source="$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)\EULA\EULA.rtf" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

I'm unfamiliar with wix files and how they work. It sounds like I have to change the 2nd line to a  CustomAction, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `Property` with the value of a `Property`. That would be cool, but it wouldn't work in this case anyway because `INSTALLFOLDER` would be initialized to blank.

You'll need to use `SetProperty` to set the value after calculating the directory tree via `CostFinalize`. Something like:

```xml
<SetProperty Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"
             After="CostFinalize" />
```

You'd benefit by getting a working understanding of properties and the timelines they can happen on. [Episode 32 of the Deployment Dojo](https://www.youtube.com/live/D_3MdBGVj4Q?si=IIZlMR9LaIm7fhJL://) jumps into the deep end a bit but watching that then going back to catch up on a bit of the setup (no pun intended) would provide you a lot more context.